# How can I enable audio system on Envy 15t-3200

Tags: 12.04, sound

I just received my HP Envy 15 (June 2012 model) and I cannot get my audio system to fully function.

This laptop has 6 speakers.

1.)  2 speakers on the front of the laptop (Stereo).
2.)  2 speakers above the keyboard, just before the LCD hinges.
3.)  2 Subwoofer speakers underneath the battery cover facing downward.

Only the 2 speakers in the front are working.

This is a "Beats" audio system.  There have been many beats audio laptops before this one, so maybe if someone has experience with those, it might translate to this device.

Answer (score -2):

This link could help u .. http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?cc=us&dlc=en&docname=c01912228&lc=en&os=4063&product=5278243&sw_lang=

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Also, this seems to be a link to information on how to solve a similar problem in Windows, using the Microsoft Sound Troubleshooter. It seems unlikely to apply here.

Comment: This guide is for Windows...  I don't have Windows on this machine.  This is askubuntu.